# Passing a big integer value in java

Tags: java

```
public class A{

    long set_time,ext_time,ident_time;
    long set_time2,ext_time2,ident_time2;
    BigInteger p,q,phiN,e,d,modu;
    KeyPairGenerator keygen;
    KeyPair keypair;
    RSAPublicKey publicKey;
    RSAPrivateCrtKey privateKey;
    MessageDigest H,G;
    String TM;

    public void Setup(int k)
    {
         SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
         try
         {
            set_time2 = System.nanoTime();

            keygen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            keygen.initialize(k, random);
            keypair = keygen.genKeyPair();
            privateKey = (RSAPrivateCrtKey)keypair.getPrivate();
            publicKey = (RSAPublicKey)keypair.getPublic();

            p = privateKey.getPrimeP();
            q = privateKey.getPrimeQ();
            phiN = p.subtract(BigInteger.ONE).multiply(q.subtract(BigInteger.ONE));
            e = privateKey.getPublicExponent();
            modu = privateKey.getModulus();
            d = e.modInverse(phiN);

            set_time = System.nanoTime() - set_time2;  

         }
         catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("\nError in Setup: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }
    public BigInteger getModu()
    {
        System.out.println(modu);
        return modu;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
       A callpkg = new A();
       callpkg.Setup(2048);     
       callpkg.getModu();
       B callchild = new B();
       callchild.KeyDer();
    }
}

public class B extends A{

    long set_time,ext_time,ident_time;
    long set_time2,ext_time2,ident_time2;
    BigInteger id_hash,N,x,t,bigT,c,s;
    MessageDigest H,G;
    String TM;
    String ID = "email", M="Hello world";

    public void KeyDer()
    {
         try
         {                        
                SHIBS abc = new Function();
                ext_time2 = System.nanoTime();

                H = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
                H.update(ID.getBytes());
                id_hash = new BigInteger(H.digest());
                A call = new A();
                BigInteger aaa = call.getModu();
                System.out.println(aaa);
                N = privateKey.getModulus();
                x = id_hash.modPow(d, N);

                ext_time = System.nanoTime() - ext_time2;
         }
         catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("\nError in KeyDer: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I'm new to programming.First time post on internet, sorry for being alot mistake
NPE occur at System.out.println("\nError in KeyDer: " + e.getMessage());
I need to use N = privateKey.getModulus(), so i have to call privateKey.getModulus() or get variable N.

Comment: I want to call getModu() at class B KeyDer() method, but i get NPE error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are Creating an instance of `A` and calling setup - This is fine.

Then you are creating an instance of B which extends A. This extension is not the same instance as created first. So two options:

1. Call `setup()` on your B instance in your `main` method

   ```
   B callchild = new B();
   callchild.Setup((2048);     
   callchild.getModu();
   callchild.KeyDer();
   ```
2. In the constructor of `B` add a call to `setup()`

EDIT Below was valid for original post

`privateKey` is a local variable for the method `setup()` of Class A;

Make the variable `RSAPrivateCrtKey privateKey` or the variables

```
BigInteger p,q,phiN,e,d,modu;
```

have class scope i.e. define them outside setup and also ensure you call `setUp()`

Comment: edited code, so sorry for mistake @@

Comment: Thanks!! I didn't run my class A setup! so that why i get NPE !!!

Answer (score 0):

You never called your `setup()` method.
Therefore, all of your fields are `null`.

Comment: edited code, so sorry for mistake @@